# Bash equivalent of Matlab's `fscanf`

Tags: bash, matlab

I have lots of text files which contains columns of numeric values (number of columns are different for each files). I use MATLAB to store each one's content like this:

```
id1 = fopen('texfile.txt','r');
A = fscanf(id1,'%f',[1 Inf]);
fclose(id1);
```

I wanted to know that if there is any simple way in bash script to do the same for me?

Comment: How are your rows separated ? by spaces ? semicolon ? As a side note, you should clarify your question a bit (I didn't understand you wanted to store a file in an array until you wrote your comment on Roberto Reale's answer)

Comment: @Ploutox The Matlab tag is a hint that the OP is not referring to C's `fscanf`, but something a bit more involved. I've now edited the question to make it clearer, and removed the `fscanf` tag, which explicitly refers to C and C++'s `fscanf`.

Comment: As most Bash users will not know matlab, I would recommend the inclusion of a small example input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

A simple equivalent of `fscanf` in Bash is the `read` builtin:

```
read -r A
```

If, on the other hand, we have got multiple columns of values, then `awk` can be used to extract the `n`-th column:

```
awk '{print $n}' < input > output
```

Comment: Thanks, but would you please provide more explanation? I mean reading an example txt file and store its content to an array or another file?

Answer (score 0):

Not the simplest way imaginable, but you could use Bash arrays (Bash 4 and up).

First, read the file using newline as separator:

```
IFS_prev="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'; 
    A=($(cat "textfile.txt"))
IFS="$IFS_prev"
```

then, to refer to the `j`<sup>th</sup> element in the `i`<sup>th</sup> row, use this:

```
row=(${A[i]})     # extract ith row and split on spaces
element=${row[j]} # extract jth element
```